# Select corresponding column value for max value of separate column(from a specific range of column) of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```py
        year    month       quantity
DateNew         
2005-01 2005    January     49550
2005-02 2005    February    96088
2005-03 2005    March       28874
2005-04 2005    April       66917
2005-05 2005    May         24070
... ... ... ...
2018-08 2018    August      132629
2018-09 2018    September   104394
2018-10 2018    October     121305
2018-11 2018    November    121049
2018-12 2018    December    174984
```

This is the data frame that I have. I want to select the maximum quantity for each year and return the corresponding month for it.

I have tried this so far

```
df.groupby('year').max()
```

But in this, I get the max value for each and every column and hence getting September in each year.
I have no clue how to approach the actual solution.

Comment: `df.groupby('year').idxmax()`?

Comment: Yes this is working fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('year')['quantity'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
         year     month  quantity
DateNew                          
2005-02  2005  February     96088
2018-12  2018  December    174984
```

Or just for the months:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('year')['quantity'].idxmax(), 'month']
```

Output:

```
DateNew
2005-02    February
2018-12    December
Name: month, dtype: object
```

Also, you can use `sort_values` followed by `duplicated`:

```
df.loc[~df.sort_values('quantity').duplicated('year', keep='last'), 'month']
```

Comment: Do i need to import something for idxmax, because for the first 2 i get 'ValueError: cannot infer type for <class 'NoneType'>'
The last one worked

Comment: @KunalGoel no, it's a Pandas function, should not require anything special. Not sure why it happens to you.